php localhost can see file on separate drive but cannot display it
been banging my head against the wall for a couple days trying to figure this out.  Building an app intended to only run on localhost.  I am on Windows 10 with Apache and PHP 8.1 installed, with the server running in a folder on C:. The app is made for uploading and viewing images.
At this point I can upload an image file, save it to an uploads folder on D:, and create a thumbnail version that saves to a thumbnails folder also on D:.  It also saves the file name to a database along with some other info.  All that works great.
The part I am having trouble with is getting images to display.

I know the files exist as I can see them in file explorer
Programmatically I know they exist, because I have tested using is_file("D:/imagefolder/image_file.jpg"), file_exists("D:/imagefolder/image_file.jpg"), and even @getimagesize("D:/imagefolder/image_file.jpg"), which all return true.
at this point I am trying to do a simple <img src="D:/imagefolder/image_file.jpg"> right after the test, but phpstorm says it can't find the file and it won't display on the page.

I have tried modifying the <Directory> in the Apache config files and the open_basedir in the php.ini files, but that just made things worse, so I reverted those back.
I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas of what is going on or things I can try.  Thanks.

img src requires the file use a file path that's accessible to the web browser, so it must be somewhere in the web root. When you use D: in an img src,  it's considered a local file path, and Windows will look for that file in its own system. Linux and Mac do not use that path type, so will do something else. All images must be accessible when doing http://example.com/path/to/image

If you really want the browser to load the images directly from the local filesystem, then the URLs must start with file:///.

Thanks for the suggestions.  As soon as I get home I will work in that direction.

Windows paths are the the other way! 'D:\\imagefolder\\image_file.jpg'. The HTML source must point to the directory relative to the webservers document root.

Yep, using a filesystem file path in an img src makes no sense in 99.99% of cases, because it tries to then load it from the user's local machine, not from your webserver. (When you're testing, that might be the same machine, but in a real situation it never would be.) You really need to supply a HTTP URL which points to a valid location on your server, accessible over the web.

@ADyson "a file path in an img src makes no sense" Well it does here because the OP said "an app intended to only run on localhost" (although I agree it would be better not to bypass the web server).

@Olivier absolutely,  it would be far more robust. And if they one day decide that they want to widen use of the app, there's a lot less work to do

@Olivier I tried a quick test at work using your suggestion, but that didn't work.

Also tried switching them like @Markus Zeller suggested, but still didn't work.

@ADyson, I understand your point, but at this time, this app is only to be used on my local machine.  Sometime way in the future I will put it on a real server and images will be stored on an AWS S3 or something similar, but for now I am just trying to access files locally, so the question is what is the path that will allow that to happen, or is there not one?

See here: "Many browsers, for security reasons, do not allow linking from a file that is loaded from a server to a local file. So, you may not be able to do this from a page loaded via HTTP; you may only be able to link to file: URLs from other local pages"

Does anyone know If I set up an alias in Apache to the folder on D:, would I be able to reference files in that folder like http://localhost:8080/imagefolder/image_file.jpg

Yes, it should work.

Yes of course you can do that, an alias is likely to be the best way

ok I will give that a shot when I get home.  Unfortunately cant do it with my set up at work

Adding the alias in Apache worked.  Thank you for all the help.

It is not possible to display images using the img html tag unless that image is accessible from the internet / network.
You can get around this by reading the file in PHP, base64 encoding it and using this: (edit: this IS inefficient)
<img src="data:{mimeType};{base64EncodedDataHere}" />

Example:
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAABC1BMVEX///9ugbYAAABofLNkebIxMTG0vNZme7PM0uNvg7psf7VfdbBugrf6+vmmpqbZ3evByN1gaYLGxsbj4+MUFBR1dXX5+v17e3tbX25HR0fj5vCfn59dY3Sjrs6zs7OsrKyZpcna2tpga4lqamonJydhYWF9jb3s7vNpeaFecZtSWW9YXGjDyt/v7+5RUVGUlJSJiYmlrMaVnrx/iq2LmcJqeqgwOE9SYIg8PDxJSUk6RGC+vr6gp7uMlrehqMR6hqtGSFJER1QVGSNEUHEcHBxOXIFebpuNkJt4g5+Um7CvtMPIy9VcaY2Di6Bygq5XYn88PkkqKzEzMi8XFAhqc425vMYhJzcQExtobn7lTKS4AAAN2ElEQVR4nO2ceVfbOBfGlcRxYschCQEHAoEkhGxkoyQllLK9BTod6NDOTJfv/0neKzmLrmLLzsIy5+g3Z/5oMaof6+rRla5sQhQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhcKNpG3XELb92re0AuxaPhVP68fvLk6AK0ad0mjcU07vG1eXXz7+eMjXXvtW54UpO76kvGNcACcTmfX6SCcoPbk/ZTz+8eXPh+x/oF/tGu01xjEw1ngxligqbJzA/49j7u7KX0Hna4vwgsVkq5UGJgrHEpk+0PbXmMFgRmHZ4Qn49+PDW4tbqi6VigNMYdpReFns96tVyzLHhDgsyzAMK2SZg8GAiRwpLGeAp6dm8/OPt9KZYJJ5qo8JZBL1QrFftczIrCw3LKbVCEG3Nhx9DrvNN6GSqqOkHIktvdCvxmJBhLlIdYTWxyp3gWZzd6f0+vIcgelC32Li5teGu9SRuTtmC7py/TXksZE3FpguQM9FlhXHyYTepCq3mMSto6OblxZp5+MsLqnEeKGvgbpViUMyB/XMFgM03nRfbkzmqaM4CvVi6FnUjYGIrZdBH+X65mgv+QLy7FS6xUwzFdf7dNw9nzwH2pXlkcbrb8/ekbW4nnYU6hCbQdVFYhwLisw4Eq+/HTynt+ZhKk9ThXrRDCwvFIrpTh7gUF1AIhPZ2OpcU751nst18iwZg3sE45wnNmNp1ExNW0giHZOD8vUZ1fj9WTTm9WMmELovMt+dabV2eMo6SSyokHXk4/X29fX28PvZqjXW9MtjqvC4P1f3MRJknVOYzC/ahwwI1qPt7e1h9FdnpZ6TfgcCj/Xj+cLTwayS7lTgLUkv4jVI4+BmOBxGK+HcyuaO1DtYA8FSoTpneDpECuRwqvCAFBdqBWts3PwdrVTC4b2V6LOPmUDQt9jUF2sRLkh3yGJeOqMxWrnd2Ahvt5cXmLqAFezlZX/hmV3Lr8posMa7f0BhOLy/rMBjJvDCWjx1WanR8BpD71mLnaVGY+3igiqsLpOaVckOp5C0ljSaKZZx6rS5RJITP6EKL0LLCIwUycFU4CEpLG00U8bduLaowOMrukW2VAeyjGZjqrBLlmwOM+7GzcUEvruiXbjECGRo+eQzGM0EY/A/2u72IgIvrk5OLk5c9UU8cFvmJ0iJU9jOJ6YXz04/plfLEc8NBMNgkVqZ22+SJyDw5C/XZmMF3YNCsaolNLxrSNZ4o8nzF/etBFqCRfreDfdNuNZd4yfa8sacEu2rqytPgWnpr9biRW06I5hFsskbjUg+3U9MvKcqv6mUbmlud+QMxjkl0g3qE8s9LmCtsBF1Zdg56O7RhLhljR93TCcVLivFF+d21iEnsfXRfUN+J2m5R1vO9xMuGo17J+Wdg4s6KPQQKEzhLuRggkqP7kRLEfnFt902sfvsgWjxAC3nqy6x6kgcBhd4KROI1wrubJdIzTHhhF3yu5h6fYHetpZHyYErwxIpuGRFjsSDoALTjXr96i8PgcJawYseYTOfaZJ9/4vDbULz3gThkwMvckR3k8jG4k4wgfn7er3uKVBYK3hyRojFjCYX5GpiazQ4yG2Aa4fuvcgcNVgCV5cKFNYK3nRILRGK6CQa5OIcxCkER9L/yjCd3t1WOs68GETgMcRo3Vugv9GM6RI94ms0Y2DNAcHhP2YZPdslM7IM+qNcwBiVCBTWCjKyRAtiNIxzooHRrPlf6LTslr87buMfp1fQhQMvHw0xo+HsILq/NqLbm/GfAxgwZI/7i9zmmIMz4doeqYLRcMlBRdbyoVsnhowP9I78BD7cNxrSLsRrhR765bYwjSTzfdKb/hGnx6Vt/tJNUrQIP2Y35S27LlFYnJ77KKTV9YFMIV4r7JFRpdeq9gstmySRr+wRnXA6eqTQH1EsxJEeukNVJPyY3ScWbnmIWtbdclTjLuyb2qROQaEhU4jXCiU7Ma7RmxEtUcRumCM1/qb3SGxS0o9pFgrgTdJPe7ccS2D54c2U62aI8StMV2gyLiBIZaNwZq2A/yWtiPIdCMssvmn+USETgnGYQslBErccKyKDG9ruCmkndmQCa42r+4ZUIF4rRGFCkPTwBiHnno8DK9wnCZtPDmZ2jgVX9lhJs5Eo22F8OK1fybsQjIZbK+RIEY94PEph/uWMZogfRwKpL9kaIdxQm9k51lK4ZQ+F1E5ludvxaaMuFSisFfaJsPQWZnhCOl6PQ0jgSapP8M6xcB+xOG7ZXaFF50RZmH489fEZIVhK4rwkPmnvx4ET+Fui6yjAZzZ0xGfnsd9jOP/s4gqFtQIRLU2r8dYylBgNTuAhKFPIW2d2jnE6XHF3Gic73ZAMRFAoH4Z4rVAh4rSEk9YDidHgO14jMZsfs+GZEhUOnkOvrXPqphuSutvH00fpdC+sFTZFoxGS1i4/1ITHgZ8FBCXhk4PZnWM8S3XjHlvnNDmVKnx8lAoURsOaaAfC6vicNxrhceBnQfM7oURlii3zq+Nz3WPr3BosqVAwGh87aHs/DrzZD0GpozE7azTYStueW+eWr0K50cSkdmBGUOhFCT/U8OPACTwYTRyN2faM0SCnvfXeOjeWVIjWChuiHWg6CtIdSV0NpwY7xKxho2lhhTEddbnnMFxaIRgNyjsEOzBRpEGQckYjPI6EOPuh5GDGaCIoHMJt74Ktv0KZQCGxECrWZiJP+IXtIZEU8LE1tgWjEUtU0DKnH5IW7/qO7zgsSxUmat52QPdk0P5GSXRH/mmgBB6MpiAxmkgihfc3Sq6rQ0egr5eW5ctfdzsw6QquYOOt0QNCvAv4eLMfglIwmhrfctFG/gaXe3eh/3xYluU02GjgySccQn26ZE/i7dykLTOaFA5Kq4bz8NaoZZO1LOy5JiV1ZN+c5rEsy0vhySM74Cn10F3AbF+QFPDxvMqMhhuzHXnLeUmV1TcvfSyXZQqR0Wyujzhfm90N65G4pIAvJPDtfBWN2YNJy/uzLeeIrCrtt7b4ExRKBiI+gyfjkNQSkgK+sNlPWgUStOUO6UvOOviuDx9AYd27E/GyXCrQNmUFfJzAd6jRBNxI7zhlKs8u9Fvjt+/KkjAFo/GtqzE2iW2ZYgHf22h6pBqgrsY4cK3KcArZvyVRSL6CQk83hfy+43cLlDVih0xxUy7uvQt1LhiNNzt+An332kjpSdKJQn7vwTBL8popzOkdbDQRNMFla9hovIhmSV9+oirAfin5V9KJQepqlXNCdFrhxnO6YDTCvBoPYjS35yTvczw5yJ43eaCd6KHQv65GK/gp55QCHmrnhI+uCNrs3yaFVpCW7aLfaaNAdQvyR9nLTmUF/MrZQfecphLx6kgKHmptdH4dz6s5qdGMW84XE34n4piR+h9XyN5lyhnXOMVbFGezv0pP0kwOAGn4jVdkNFoc/yIu4M/eo53SLV99geuH5ONTJuO6wsD7f5C0TKGvHFYTmoZ2fOP8BWjn2DRb/A/7uICfq01/1IKW+xGv01AIy3ICIgD03T83P8VGs0cSk9dgtJjLuTNT49+UwT81+R9pGi7g7+mJacPBX4kLXscn2U8g0WUoYqPJ1lZ2ylAo4GcXOnE9z1kM8gPiNDOYkSgc9vXeKpkXoYBPFjknPdd5GkK+uEnE+39Dsa62BLiAH3Wt0fsw55koSN5cJOL9v5zrmZbFqKKCdy41f3DMfa4NUpvMjESxgL/A6zPuwCyESlTzB8cCZxNJMjMjcaaAvyKBNDhQy2ItxF/gIudLQeKT4KjSAv4ygNGgit28r6UudkYYJP77hOZFnwL+EuACfmXOs+4Ln/MmI7vJhEYa8VphpoC/BBYq4HucI/EU6JzVd8khg/ClmZlGqk8Bf3EgOFCJKj1HcCz5vgVM/UxiOUTzcJ8C/uIsYTRLvzMDCVxm4qkwWpJTVmg09Og/33Lg4FjFe0/AZ9qNu+WQYfZTHHH5mZR5MM0433LgFzANcxXvrgEPLFJ364apcawsJ6US+Ya1gAINZ45YwfuHhLS/Nkehurp+WxbDOP3F9J2t4B1SQruRheqb0WgY9z+dDlzNe8CUj83dzO4b0TjVt7nK74BkvzbZ53BeXSPE50jf9qq/AVL6TfsRNNYt+cm3Z5Vn3P0aJXfP8d2Ih99OP+6WX6cjDWPwYZQW3Ppuii6rkXbky4o0puHJ9tWfjdLX5rQjX0ykBe7yfpzWrfybHyK1nbHGFxIJvXc/jk7wzxf5WNSP31ORdfopp+dUFzqdyqusvcR3ohjZSUdubWXqA+M5VNLv091/+jmRx8o+L8nD52ZzayQSunJgrDBi2df37u/eT9WFD5/TXaQimyOR0JePg9DyMp1PC95/4tWFD15FnkNpZwu6cmv82bjdzCPrzQWEMmkw5Z1+ev+LVxfOvconBXlqP6ArjyYij0Y6Q84d+0kdCaP9dvrpw88w5nDt1b99OSL74/PRDWijGkdfyIM/ZMrlRn0w0epGaDBoPD41b75V/gGwutf86KUrtfWd3zc3R+5ALDczT1Pgj036zS7g72g0Wqnc3m5sTIoGw9zeW+m7GbLra9CbLkKvEdsOVODQEThW1+ntvbWucyGZXd//vEmF3lzP8o0xpP9Fo9+/fx+J297s7pVebEJfEe3S+vn+2o5D141er9vd2T8vZf9r0hQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhUKhUCgUCoVCoVAoFAqFQqFQKBQKhWIJ/g9BcPCGK9doegAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />


Thanks Erik,  Your solution worked as well, but as you said it is inefficient, so I will stick with using the Alias.
